# Hbase schema design suggestion

Tags: nosql, schema, hbase

Coming from RDBMS background, I need little help/suggestion to design Hbase schema for below usecase.

It is a report generating application using hadoop. Now, we need to track all previous report generation history for a particular user based on his email id. So, data need to be persisted are, email id, report name, start date, end date, status. I am planning to keep the email id as row key and other entities as columns,
emailId(row key) - (columns) appName:reportName, appName:startDate, appName:endDate, appName:status

But the problem is, the same user can run same report for different date ranges. So it will overwrite the appName:reportName and appName:status columns. Since I am new to NoSQL world, I am not sure how to tackle this problem.
Can someone please suggest me an ideal way of designing schema for this requirement?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: For HBase, the pattern that you plan to use for querying the data is often more important than the particular data being stored. Are you planning on querying by user Id?  By report ID?  Both?  Also, it seems like you would need to store the time stamp of the moment that the user ran the report, right?

Comment: I am planning to query by user id. Will it be correct? Or which one would be the best way? I am open for any suggestion. Yes, I need to store the timestamp as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your expected query pattern, here is what I'd suggest:

```
RowKey                                 | Column Family (appName)                   |
userid@domain.com-YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SSS | reportName | status | startDate | endDate |
```

This design gives you a few advantages.  First of all, you can quickly query (using a scan) all rows for a particular user over a particular date range.  Secondly, you are avoiding write hotspots by preceding the timestamp in the rowkey with the user's ID.

You can write one row to this schema each time a user triggers the generation of a report, and you won't need to worry about overwriting the columns (unless a user generates two reports in the same 1/10th of a second).